# browserify exclude cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am trying to get a node module to work in the browser, but I don't want browserify to include the require inline as I am loading it separately.

The problem is that even though I'm loading superagent with a `<script>` tag, browserify throws an exception: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module superagent'`

#### shell

`browserify --x superagent source.js -o output.js`

#### jade

```
script(src='/bower/superagent/superagent.js')
script(src='/js/output.js')
```

#### souce.js

```
var superagent = require('superagent');
module.exports = { }
```

How can I exclude a require() from the browser without it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

`browserify -i superagent --standalone iceberg source.js > output.js`

then in the browser just reference the standalone parameter:

```
<script>
 iceberg.lettuce.eat();
</script>
```

http://www.forbeslindesay.co.uk/post/46324645400/standalone-browserify-builds